# Scheduling Multiple Cron Jobs for a REST API connector in Fivetran

Tags: cron

We use a Fivetran connector that pulls our data every five minutes. We do not need the data pulled that frequently during non working hours. The connector we have does not allow for customization, but a REST API was suggested if paired with a cron job. Is it possible to set up a schedule like this?

**Monday** 4:00am to 11:55pm, run every five minutes. 12:00am to 4:00am, run on the hour
**Tuesday** 4:00am to 11:55pm, run every five minutes. 12:00am to 4:00am, run on the hour
**Wednesday** 4:00am to 11:55pm, run every five minutes. 12:00am to 4:00am, run on the hour
**Thursday** 4:00am to 11:55pm, run every five minutes. 12:00am to 4:00am, run on the hour
**Friday** 4:00am to 11:55pm, run every five minutes. 12:00am to 4:00am, run on the hour
**Saturday** run every hour
**Sunday** run every hour

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like:

```
*/5 4-23 * * 1-5 /command/to/run
0 0-4 * * 1-5 /command/to/run
0 * * * 6-7 /command/to/run
```

first will run every 5 minutes (`*/5) from 4 to 23h (14-23`) from Monday to Friday (`1-5`)
next will run 0 minutes from `0-4` hours from Monday to Friday (`1-5`)
The last one will run 0 minutes, every hour (`*`) Saturday and Sunday (`6-7`)

FYI `cron` use 24 hours notation!